# PHP assets not being served by nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I've installed a WP blog and added a location block for it on the nginx server block configuration. When visiting the blog at `example.com/blog` or any of the blog posts like `example.com/blog/foo-bar-baz` the content is served but all assets are missing.

When I check the logs it looks like all requests to those asset URLs are being permanently redirected to the root blog URL. Here's an example of a request from nginx's access log:

```
"GET /blog/wp-includes/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://example.com/blog/" "USER_AGENT_STRING"
```

Below is the nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  root /home/example/current/public;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location ~ /blog {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/blog/index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_buffers 256 128k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

How can I edit either of the location blocks to have nginx catch the requests for all URLs that contain either `/blog/wp-content/` or `/blog/wp-includes/`? I've tried adding the following location block but it did not work:

```
location ~ ^(/wp-content/|/wp-includes/)/.*\.(jpe?g|gif|css|png|js|ico|pdf|m4a|mov|mp3)$ {
  root /var/www/blog;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration does not appear to have the ability to serve static content. A more conventional approach would be to use a nested location to serve the dynamic content. For example:

```
location ^~ /blog {
    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.